# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object Image Docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker

I tried to found this answer a week. This look like easy to fix. but i got some image on docker that return this message error:

```
{
  "ClassName": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",
  "Message": "Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[bank.Domain.Dto.DtoPriceCrypto]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\nPath 'code', line 2, position 9.",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": "   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)\n   at bank.Domain.Nomics.GetInfoPriceCrypto(DtoGetInfoCrypto infoCrypto) in /app/Domain/Nomics.cs:line 49\n   at bank.Domain.Wallet.SaldoWalletPessoa(Int32 crytoUserID) in /app/Domain/Wallet.cs:line 127\n   at bank.Controllers.WalletController.SaldoWallet(DtoResquestWalletPessoa walletPessoa) in /app/Controllers/WalletController.cs:line 36",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": null,
  "HResult": -2146233088,
  "Source": "Newtonsoft.Json",
  "WatsonBuckets": null
}
```

when i try to use on my computer its works fine.

dockerfile

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS base
> WORKDIR /app
> COPY *.csproj ./
> RUN dotnet restore
>
> COPY . ./
> RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o publish
>
> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
> WORKDIR /app
> COPY --from=base /app/publish .
> ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "bank.dll", "/app/publish"]
>
> CMD  ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://*:$PORT" dotnet bank.dll

there is way to fix this into dockerfile ?

i tried to pull image docker on my pc and didnt get result. because its works in my localhost

Comment: From the message alone it's not possible to tell what exactly is going wrong. The fact that JSON deserialization is failing only shows the app isn't deserializing the same thing in the container as it does on your machine, but you need to know *why*, and that means digging deeper. For example, the container may be running into a network issue where it gets back a different response because it's using a different configuration file, or DNS resolution is different from the host. You need to log the actual requests and responses and use that to proceed.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The dockerfile is the wrong place to look for now. You have to troubleshoot your bank/crypto/whatever software you are running in there. (Note how both the exception message and the stacktrace include custom app-specific types whose type names involve terms like "Crypto", "Bank", "Saldo", etc.) Start with finding a way to actually inspect the exact json data/document which that software is processing and that leads to the error/exception, and compare it with a json document/data which does not produce the problems. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) When knowing more details about the differences between a working and a not-working json document (the error message in your question gives a first hint you should not ignore), you then need to get smart about what those differences in these two json documents signify and therefore how you might fix the software, change its settings or change something in the environment the software is running (whether it's docker-related or related to something else in your computing or network environment) to avoid the problem.

Comment: ok, guys everybody is right. I solve my problema. Its was the response request. Its means that API of binance block request on container country. and i change location my container and solved.